# Optimum install error : Could not open 'optimum/version.py' due [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'

Tags: pip, python-3.8, rhel7, large-language-model, ppc64le

I am trying to setup [openllm](https://github.com/bentoml/OpenLLM) repository on IBM ac922 GPU server with operating system Red Hat Enterprise Linux(7.6) and architecture ppc64-le. It requires me to install all dependencies from pyproject.toml file which has optimum as one of the dependency. The dependencies are installed using command :
pip install openllm
But when I am trying to install all the dependencies m getting this error:

```
AssertionError: Error: Could not open 'optimum/version.py' due [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'
This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I had created the virtual env with python 3.8.17. I removed this optimum package from pyproject.toml file but still it was trying to install this package. I also tried to put condition where it install version >= 1.0.0. Still, it tried to install the all the versions of optimum. I also upgraded my pip and I have tried using pip3 also to install all the packages.

What is the ideal solution to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with optimum support on ppc64le. I'm not entirely sure if it is supported.

You might have to build optimum from source. Best to refer to [optimum's repository](https://github.com/huggingface/optimum) for more information.